# "width" not found in .place with customTkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout, customtkinter

I have this code of a frame in `customTkinter` version `5.2.0`:

```
import customtkinter as ctk

# window
window = ctk.CTk()
window.geometry('400x300')

# widget
frame = ctk.CTkFrame(window)
frame.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, width = 20, anchor = 'center')

# run
window.mainloop()
```

But for some reasons it gives me the error:

```
'width' and 'height' arguments must be passed to the constructor of the widget, not the place method
```

In tkinter this works just fine, and I also saw people that use the `place` method in this exactly way with the same library and don't have my problem: [python tkinter place method from right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72812276/python-tkinter-place-method-from-right)

I also tried to use `width` in both `place` and the definition of the frame, but this didn't work. I can't use `relwidth` or `relheight` because lately I want to resize the frame in a particular way with the window.

Comment: It is raised by `customtkinter` internally which is added after v5.0.4.  As the error suggests, you can specify the `width` in `ctk.CTkFrame(...)` instead.

Comment: @acw1668 thank you, why did they remove this options?

Comment: I don't know because I am not the author.